# undefined local variable or method NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am putting together a ruby program that retrieves stock quotes from yahoo. It works fine for one stock, but when I try to loop through my array of stocks I get the following error:

```
nyahoo.rb:20:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `stock' for main:Object (NameError).
```

Below is the code, I would be grateful for any input on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

symbol = ['ARRS','BCST']

symbol.each do |s| 

@page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=#{s.upcase}&ql=1"))

end

def marketCap(stock)

  return  @page.xpath("//td[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']")

end


ask = marketCap(stock)[3].text.split('x')
puts ask[0]
```

Comment: It error message says "There is no variable or method called `stock`" and it is referring to the `ask = marketCap(stock)..` line (#20). I'd have to agree given the provided code as the identifier only appears as a parameter. The array has nothing to do with it; this is an additional programming error.

Comment: This won't work as you intend since you fetch several pages and over-write `@page` with the result each time.

Answer (score 2):

Fix needed this part `marketCap(stock)[3].text.split('x')`. Pass some real value istead of *stock*.

Comment: Your right, as I reviewed the code I see your point, I looped through the symbols to get the appropriate pages and stored them in @page, how would I pass the symbols to ask = marketCap(stock)[3].text.split('x')

Comment: @rahrahruby inside the method `marketCap(stock)`, I don't see any place where you used `stock`. Then why are you passing `stock` to that method?